# How to import data from another Google Sheet using Google Script without using Spreadsheet ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Script that imports my data range from one Google Sheet to another Google Sheet and it works perfectly.

My issue is however the original data sheet gets updated daily by a third party (CloudHQ) which replaces the original version, this means that a new spreadsheet ID is created which renders this script incorrect daily.

Is there a way to import a data range by another google script method by using something constant such as the file name or file location?

Please find my code below:

```
    var sourceSpreadsheetID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var sourceWorksheetName = "CustomSheetName1";
    var targetSpreadsheetID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var targetWorksheetName = "Sheet1";

function importData1() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  //var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("B:B");

  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
  toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

Comment: Does you third party replace sheets contained in the spreadsheet or the whole spreadsheet (source or target)? If the latter is the case, is the spreadsheetname and the folder where it is contained still the same and you have only one spreadsheet with this name inside the same folder?

Comment: Try looking at the DriveApp reference. That should get you going. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Comment: @ziganotschka it replaces the entire spreadsheet. That's correct yes, the file name stays exactly the same and there's only 1 file in that folder with that name.

Comment: How to get data for a specific range from the "thisWorksheet"? I want to get data for the "B1:B21"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to browse your Drive for a file with the given name and find out its ID

Sample for retrieving the ID of the source spreadsheet

```
  var fileName = "PASTE HERE THE NAME OF YOUR SOURCE SPREDSHEET";
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
  var sourceSpreadsheetID = file.getId();
  var sourceWorksheetName = "CustomSheetName1";
  var targetSpreadsheetID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var targetWorksheetName = "Sheet1";

  function importData1() {
    var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
    var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
    //var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
    var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("B:B");

    var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
    var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
    var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
    toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
  }
```

If it is the ID of the destination spreadsheet you want to retrieve - proceed respectively.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka. For some reason the data isn't updating with the current data however, it seems to be getting it from a version that was moved to the Google drive bin.

Comment: This means that you have more than 1 file with the same name on your drive. In this case the only way to distinguish the files from each other is to have your file of interest in a designated folder (with know name or better - id). In this case you can specify in which folder to look for the file. Otherwise, make sure that you do not have versions with the same name in the bin or nywhere on your drive.

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes sense. How do I got about telling it what folder to look in? My folder name is called "Run Data 2020".

Comment: from the reference: `getFoldersByName(name)`

Comment: `var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next(); var file = folder.getFilesByName(fileName).next();` Make sure the folder name is unique.

Comment: @ziganotschka I've added it to my code but now I'm getting the below error message:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 2, file "Channel Reference Import.gs")

He'res my code:

var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(Run Data 2020).next();
var file = folder.getFilesByName(30 Day data).next();
var sourceSpreadsheetID = file.getId();
var sourceWorksheetName = "CustomSheetName1";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var targetWorksheetName = "Sheet1";

Comment: You need to put the name of the folder in quotes:  "Run Data 2020" - same for the file name

Comment: @ziganotschka Managed to fix the error. Turns out there was a file with the same name on a shared folder I have access to. Renamed my file to something very unique and now it's resolved. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: IMHO it's not a good practice to make calls to Google Apps Script classes in the global scope, especially if there isn't a way to catch errors. Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/q/63170784/1595451?